# How do I use glutBitmapString() in C++ to draw text to the screen?

Tags: c++, graphics, glut

I'm attempting to draw text to the screen using GLUT in 2d.

I want to use glutBitmapString(), can someone show me a simple example of what you have to do to setup and properly use this method in C++ so I can draw an arbitrary string at an (X,Y) position?

```
glutBitmapString(void *font, const unsigned char *string);
```

I'm using linux, and I know I need to create a Font object, although I'm not sure exactly how and I can supply it with the string as the second arguement.  However, how do I also specify the x/y position?

A quick example of this would help me greatly.  If you can show me from creating the font, to calling the method that would be best.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to use [`glRasterPos`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glrasterpos) to set the raster position before calling `glutBitmapString()`.  Note that each call to `glutBitmapString()` advances the raster position, so several consecutive calls will print out the strings one after another.  You can also set the text color by using [`glColor()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glcolor).  The set of available fonts are listed [here](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node76.html#SECTION000111000000000000000).

```
// Draw blue text at screen coordinates (100, 120), where (0, 0) is the top-left of the
// screen in an 18-point Helvetica font
glRasterPos2i(100, 120);
glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glutBitmapString(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, "text to render");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help adam.  Also, for a long time it kept telling me glutBitmapString was not defined, and I eventually found it named as "_glutBitmapString" in GL/glui.h.  Any idea why?

Comment: `glutBitmapString` is an extension implemented on `freeglut`, no present in the old `glut`, `GL/freeglut.h` must be included instead of `GL/glut.h`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Adam's answer,

```
glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);  //RGBA values of text color
glRasterPos2i(100, 120);            //Top left corner of text
const unsigned char* t = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>("text to render");
// Since 2nd argument of glutBitmapString must be const unsigned char*
glutBitmapString(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18,t);
```

Check out https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node76.html for more font options