# glutBitmapString/glutStrokeString seem to require const unsigned char* - strings don't work

Tags: c++, glut, freeglut

Ubuntu 11.04, G++, freeglut and GLUT.

I don't understand this at all. Here's the error I get:

```
whatever.cc:315:59: error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘const unsigned char*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘void glutStrokeString(void*, const unsigned char*)’
```

and if I try glutBitmapString:

```
whatever.cc:315:59: error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘const unsigned char*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘void glutBitmapString(void*, const unsigned char*)’
```

Here's the relevant code (I think).

```
scoreStream << "Score: " << score << "\0";
scoreString = scoreStream.str();

// ...in another method:

glRasterPos2i(0, 0);
glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glutBitmapString(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, scoreString);
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544079/how-do-i-use-glutbitmapstring-in-c-to-draw-text-to-the-screen/544107#544107) tells me it should work, but it just doesn't.

Quote for those who don't want to jump:

```
// Draw blue text at screen coordinates (100, 120), where (0, 0) is the top-left of the
// screen in an 18-point Helvetica font
glRasterPos2i(100, 120);
glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glutBitmapString(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, "text to render");
```

(Also, I have tried leaving a direct string like "text to render" in there. No dice.)

```
whatever.cc:315:64: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘const unsigned char*’
```

I am confused. This is my first question on SO, as far as I remember, so apologies if it isn't too well put together. I'll provide any extra information I can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no automatic conversion of an `std::string` to a `char const*`. However, you can use `std::string::c_str()` to get the `char const*` out of an `std::string`.

e.g. `glutBitmapString(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, scoreString.c_str());`

Note: The answer you linked to doesn't say that you can use `std::string`. The example it gives (`glutBitmapString(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, "text to render");`) uses a *string literal*, which is an array of `char`, not an `std::string`.

Remember that OpenGL is a C library, and `std::string` doesn't exist in C.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks! 

Edit: Nope, still get this error. It wants const _unsigned_ char* for some reason.

    whatever.cc:315:67: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘const unsigned char*’

Comment: Just cast it: `(const unsigned char*)scoreString.c_str()`

Comment: I see what you mean about using C++ things with a C library. It's my first OpenGL thing on my own, so I'm pretty inexperienced. <shrug>

Comment: Casting! Dammit, this is the first time I *haven't* tried casting. Sigh. Thanks a lot, anyway. You've saved me considerable pain there. :)

Comment: This is one of those rare times where "casting to shut up the compiler" is the correct thing to do.  But most of the time, don't do that (*especially* not with function pointers).