# text rendering issue in opengl Flight Simulator application

Tags: c++, opengl, text-rendering, opengl-compat

I am working on a flight simulator in opengl in which i have made and altitude scale with an arrow pointed towards the expected altitude values
controlling the plane with joystick i want that when changing the altitude of plane with joystick movement altitude values should be displayed in front of the pointed arrow and should move upward and downward with increasing and decreasing altitudes. 
lets say altitude values should be displayed starting from 0 to never ending value.
just to be clear i have a variable in which values are updating correctly when i cout them the problem is with text rendering.

i have tried using `glutBitmapCharacter()`.

```cpp
void text(float px,float py,int v)
{
    glRasterPos2f(px ,py);
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, v); 
}
```

and this is how i am calling

```cpp
text(2.11,0-x[4]/200,48)
```

`x[4]` has altitude values

i want `v` to be generated depending upon `x[4]` values. 
say `if x[4]= 200` then function should be called 3 times with `v` values `50,48,48`

Comment: What have you tried? what was the result? show a [mre]

Comment: What is the question? Is your code not working? What is happening? What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use glutBitmapString to print multiple characters to the screen. You can use std::ostringstream or snprintf() to convert your number to a string.

(See: [How do I use glutBitmapString() in C++ to draw text to the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544079/how-do-i-use-glutbitmapstring-in-c-to-draw-text-to-the-screen))